# Managing very complex expression with sed

Tags: shell-script, sed, scripting, bashrc

I'm trying to write a script that would replace that line:

```
 [ "$PS1" = "\\s-\\v\\\$ " ] && PS1="[\u@\h \W]\\$ "
```

with that line:

```
# [ "$PS1" = "\\s-\\v\\\$ " ] && PS1="[\u@\h \W]\\$ "
```

and that will add that new line:

```
[ "$PS1" = "\\s-\\v\\\$ " ] && PS1="[\u@\h \D{%T} \W]\\$ "
```

to the `/etc/bashrc` file.
Basically, I want the script to comment the old settings and add a timestamp next to the username in the prompt (the new setting).
I have tried to do the first part like this:

```
pattern=' [ "$PS1" = "\\s-\\v\\\$ " ] && PS1="[\u@\h \W]\\$ "'
sudo sed 's/${pattern}/#${pattern}/' < /etc/bashrc
```

But it didn't work, I think it's becouse of the special chars in the string. But I'm not sure which chars do I need to escape.
The last part supposed to be just something like this:

```
sed -i '  [ "$PS1" = "\\s-\\v\\\$ " ] && PS1="[\u@\h \D{%T} \W]\\$ "' /etc/bashrc
```

Will apriciate some guidness.

Thanks

Comment: 1st rule before any attempt to answer: don't `sudo` or work on system files (`/etc/bashrc`) while you haven't thoroughfully tested your shell script on crash files without any priviledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The single quotes in your `sed` script prevent the `${pattern}` from being expanded. You'd have to use double quotes (but this would lead to the mentioned problem with special chars)
2. Use `sed` addressing with enough of the given line to identify it and then insert the commenting like this: `/^ *\[ *"$PS1 =/s/^/#/`
3. Use the `a` command of `sed` to append a given line

In your case you just want to add something to the line, so

```
sed 's/\( *\[ "$PS1" = "..s-..v...$ " \] && PS1="\[.u@.h \)\(.W]..$ "\)/#\1\2\
\1\\D{%T} \2/' /etc/bashrc
```

Comment: It didn't work. It's printed the file like the changes took place (like cat the bashrc after I ran the sed), but when I open the file in vim there are no changes.

Comment: If you get the desired output, add the `-i` option to actually perform the changes. It's always a good idea to test without `-i` first, when changing system files.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to replace a whole line without regex, you could also get the line number first:

```
LNO=$(grep -FN "$pattern" </etc/bashrc | cut -d':' -f1)
```

and replace the line with commented pattern and new line:

```
[ "$LNO" ] \
&& sed -i "${LNO}s/.*/#$pattern\n$newline/" /etc/bashrc
```

This one is also clearer to read months later.

For testing purposes I always prefer to sed into a temporary file first (without -i option),
and rename it later so I don't harm my config.

But I also found that this method does not work with patterns containing `[,],$ and &`, the patterns also need some masking in this order:

```
pattern=${pattern//\[/\\\[}
pattern=${pattern//\]/\\]}
pattern=${pattern//\$/\\$}
pattern=${pattern//\&/\\&}
pattern=${pattern//\\/\\\\}
```

which leads to following function:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a commentAndReplaceMask=('[' ']' '$' '&')
function commentAndReplace () {
  local p="$1"  # pattern
  local s="$p" # sed pattern
  local r="$2"  # replacement
  local f="$3"  # file

  echo args:
  echo p: $p
  echo r: $r
  echo s: $s

  s=${s//\\/\\\\}
  r=${r//\\/\\\\}
  for m in ${commentAndReplaceMask[@]}; do
    s=${s//$m/\\$m}
    r=${r//$m/\\$m}
  done

  echo prepared for sed:
  echo p: $p
  echo r: $r
  echo s: $s

  LNO=$(grep -Fn "$p" <$f | cut -d':' -f1)

  [ "$LNO" ] \
  && sed "${LNO}s/.*/# $s\n$r/" <$f >${f}.tmp

  # mv "${f}.tmp" "$f"
}

commentAndReplace "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this kind of substitution of complex pattern with sed:

```
sed 's/${pattern}/#${pattern}/'
```

you have to force evaluation of `pattern` this way:

```
sed 's/'${pattern}'/#'${pattern}'/'
```

Check that this achieve exactly what you want on temporary file before trying to touch `/etc/bashrc` and use `sudo` (Moreover, before using `sudo` you should check you are really using the right one to avoid to use a fake one).